# Transaction as been confirmed but has not reached receiver's wallet

Tags: transactions

Transaction 26e074dda878b78b122739b6dbe65d06472bb40ca3abd047a58910016cd5467a

Receiving Wallet address: 3J4Vwkd8KBzf7Np69KWkkvzED6HyRTpL1e

Amount: 0.04457308 BTC

Comment: It's confirmed, so there's nothing you can do for the receiving wallet.

Comment: Can I resend it to a different wallet and then send it to the recipient that way? I used a bitcoin ATM to send this money. I'd rather not have just lost $700

Comment: No, but the transaction should reach the recipient. There are scams that tell users "We didn't receive your payment" so that one sends again, so if you don't trust them be careful. Otherwise, they need to fix their wallet.

Comment: re: *"Can I resend it to a different wallet and then send it to the recipient that way? I used a bitcoin ATM to send this money. I'd rather not have just lost $700"*: it sounds like you are the victim of a scam, sorry for your loss. The transaction you linked above was confirmed (completed) 2 days ago. It is **without any doubt** received by that address. If the recipient is saying they have not received it, they are either lying to you, or their wallet is not properly in sync with the network.